# XV6 os - Docker ubuntu image error: "no bootable device" / qemu-nox command

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, qemu, xv6

I am trying to run the XV6 OS on ubuntu image in a docker container (on windows).
I succeed in building the image, running it and accessing the docker container.
But inside the container cmd when I try to use the `make qemu-nox` command it crashes and gives the following error:

```
SeaBIOS (version 1.13.0-1ubuntu1)
iPXE (http://ipxe.org) 00:03.0 CA00 PCI2.10 PnP PMM+1FF8CA10+1FECCA10 CA00
Booting from Hard Disk...
Boot failed: not a bootable disk
No bootable device.
```

I am following the instructions here: https://github.com/anton-christensen/xv6-docker

I am not sure what causes this. 
The other commands such as `make`, `make clean qemu` does work without error.

Comment: On Ubuntu 19.10 I had issues booting xv6, and I don't know if it's fixed in 20.04. I used this repo with `ubuntu:18.04` as base image and everything is fine. Try 18.04 and see if it works.

Comment: @AliTou Thank you for the suggestion . Actually I have tried ```18.04``` and the rest of the available docker ubuntu image versions, unfortunately, I get the same error.

Comment: Sorry for plugging my own repo, but I've tested and can run this Docker image on Windows just fine.  It **seems** like the repo you're using doesn't include `qemu-system-common` that I needed. [Here it is](https://github.com/camerondurham/cs350-docker)

Comment: @tentative thank you for the repo, but just found these 2 docker images on docker hub, which both works perfectly for me on windows [grantbot/xv6](https://hub.docker.com/r/grantbot/xv6/) and [sembrik/xv6-aau](https://hub.docker.com/r/sembrik/xv6-aau/). And these only require docker run ```-it <image-name>``` so haven't tried your repo yet :-).

Comment: that's great! using a prebuilt docker image sounds a lot faster.